# Errorlog Duration Using Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am having the following log table in that I want to fetch error log duration that is start time end time and total duration

```
log_Name          date_time 

   ok         2019-01-31 12:20:02
   ok         2019-01-31 12:20:18
   err1       2019-01-31 12:20:20
   err1       2019-01-31 12:20:40
   err2       2019-01-31 12:20:50
   err2       2019-01-31 12:20:59
   err2       2019-01-31 12:21:05  
   err1       2019-01-31 12:21:10
   err1       2019-01-31 12:21:40
   err3       2019-01-31 12:21:50
   err3       2019-01-31 12:21:58
   err2       2019-01-31 12:22:10
   err2       2019-01-31 12:24:28
```

I want to get following result

```
log_Name      start_time         end_time             duration 

   err1   2019-01-31 12:20:20   2019-01-31 12:20:40   00:00:20     
   err2   2019-01-31 12:20:50   2019-01-31 12:21:05   00:00:15    
   err1   2019-01-31 12:21:10   2019-01-31 12:21:40   00:00:30   
   err3   2019-01-31 12:21:50   2019-01-31 12:21:58   00:00:08 
   err2   2019-01-31 12:22:10   2019-01-31 12:24:28   00:02:18
```

I am tried the following query but I am unable to find the correct way to get the result query please guide me to get correct result

```
SELECT m.log_Name as log_Nam,m.date_time as start_time FROM test as m UNION SELECT n.date_time as end_time FROM test n  where m.log_Name!='ok'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL group rows to find time difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834011/mysql-group-rows-to-find-time-difference)

Comment: CTE make an [easier form of query](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#1835)

Comment: It is not giving my solution

Comment: I didn't  find the answer please guide me to get correct result